# Install or upload laravel 5.2 into godaddy plesk?

Tags: laravel-5, plesk, shared-hosting, godaddy-api

I am wondering if there is correct way to install or upload laravel 5.2 into godaddy plesk panel

Answer (score 0):

Before Plesk 12.5 you can use zip archive and FTP.

Since Plesk 12.5 you can use `Composer` (Domain > Applications > Scan) with `composer.json` like:

```
{
  "name": "mytestapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "require": {
    "laravel/laravel": "5.2.*"
  }
}
```

Since Plesk 17.0 you can use Git.

Comment: the problem is how I can use composer, I can't find SSH ?

Comment: For Plesk 12.5: create composer.json in subscription root, click on Domain > Applications tab > Scan button - plesk finds you composer.json and can update dependencies with composer.